# Facebook ads "pixel is active but isn't associated with this account and will not track Landing Page Views"

Tags: facebook-ads-api, facebook-ads

I created a brand new Facebook ad account and am trying to set up my campaign, ad set, and ad.

I have lots of experience running Facebook ads and have never seen this error before in the ad set:

> **Pixel Isn't Tracking Landing Page Views**
>
> Your page's pixel is active
> but isn't associated with this account and will not track Landing Page
> Views. You can install a new pixel or switch back to optimizing for
> link clicks.
>
> [Learn More](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/417293491972212)

I've used the Chrome extension "Facebook Pixel Helper" to verify that the FB pixel loads (and has the correct pixel ID).

And https://business.facebook.com/events_manager2/list/pixel/xxxx/overview?business_id=xxxx shows PageView events correctly. So I don't understand the warning in the ad set or what I'm supposed to fix.

Ideas?

P.S. Given the remarkably small number of Google results, this seems to be a rare error.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I hadn't yet verified my domain at https://business.facebook.com/settings/owned-domains/xxxx?business_id=xxxx

I don't think that was the root cause, but I might as well mention it since I did go ahead and verify my domain as a first step after asking this question here.

I *think* the root cause was some confusion with WordPress.

I noticed at `/wp-admin/post.php?post=1139&action=edit` under Page Attributes it said Template: Elementor Canvas.

So I visited `/wp-admin/plugin-editor.php?file=elementor%2Fmodules%2Fpage-templates%2Ftemplates%2Fcanvas.php&plugin=elementor%2Felementor.php` and added my Google Tag Manager snippet there (in addition to in the child theme's header file at `/wp-admin/theme-editor.php?file=header.php&theme=twentyfifteen-child`).

Then I cleared my server cache and my browser cache and reloaded the landing page, and the Facebook Pixel Helper showed the pixel ID (as it did before), and now also my Ads Manager doesn't throw a warning in the ad set.

For good measure, I also edited `resources\views\layouts\assets.blade.php` (elsewhere on my server) to have the new Google Tag Manager ID rather than the old one from years ago, just in case Facebook somehow was finding that stale one.